# Relative Layouts - long Textview overlaps

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, overlap

I have a relative Layout which includes two TextViews:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context="com.example.pris.ViewActivity"
  tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myDes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/description"
    android:text="@string/myText" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/textfield"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tex"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/but"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/suchen"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="addToList" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/but2"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Liste löschen"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ex"
    android:onClick="removeList" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ex"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_below="@+id/but">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I only inserted "description" recently, the Text there is quite long  - and now it overlaps with everything below it.

How can I change that?

I do not want to change the whole Layout if possible, and unfortunately it is not possible to shorten the text.[image]

Comment: An image or screenshot in this case would be nice and easier for others to help you.

Comment: please add screen shot of this

Comment: Please use Linear Layout instead of Relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Very simply actually.

I took my original layout and added:

```
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

to the first textview. Found that on the API for TextVew.

That was all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put a ScrollView above the RelativeLayout?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>
```

Also, check the end of the .xml, you are missing the closing tag

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

you must provide alignment for your button **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"**

check

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/but"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="tex"
            android:layout_below="@id/tex"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="addToList" />
```

Here are full code for layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dumy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/description"
            android:text="tex" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/textfield"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tex"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="tex"
            android:layout_below="@id/tex"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="addToList" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but2"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Liste löschen"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ex"
            android:onClick="removeList" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ex"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/but"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and for screenshot

[image: result]

Comment: How would you help the OP? You could give any explanation with your answer instead of just handing out some code.

Comment: if I could I could downvote this it totally crashd my layout paths.

Comment: what do you mean crashed...? its just an layout, if you dont want your text overlapping other text, just use linearlayout as parent layout and then set orientation into vertical, im just trying help you :)

thanks

Comment: I sincerely apologize. Must have misscopied sth. here. That does work, however, in this case the listview does not show more than one item anymore.

Answer (score 1):

make your text scrolling by add the following features to it through the run-time:

```
TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
description.setSingleLine();
description.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
description.setSelected(true);
```

**UPDATE:**

So, you have to create a custom view:

first, create the following class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
            Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused) {
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if (focused) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

then, when defining the `TextView` in your **xml layout** define it the following way:

```
<!-- use the path of the package which you put the class ScrollingTextView in -->
<com.example.ScrollingTextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myDes"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

then when declaring it in your Activity:

```
com.example.ScrollingTextView description = (com.example.ScrollingTextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
```

Comment: Screenshot is after using your code snippet. Does not really help

Comment: I try that after work - but seriously, is there no simpler solution to get a long text into a textview without overlaps? I cannot be the first with that problem!

Comment: @user1862770 no there isn't(i think so), I told you all the possible solutions, and the last solutions isn't that complex, such a custom view to help you overcome this problem every time you face it, and believe me you will have to face it multiple times again.

Comment: I testet that. Looks EXACTLY like on the screenshot, so does not really help.

Comment: I think you made something wrong while testing, it can't be like the screen shot

Comment: I copied verbatim, thank you. It IS like the screenshot.